# Using ng-init and ng-repeat in the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm not sure it is possible to use ng-init and ng-repeat in the same div. I need it to select from the database all comments that have an id of 6.

I'm calling the code here and displaying an array:

```
< div ng-init="getComments('6')" ng-repeat="comment in comments">{{ comment.message }}< /div>
```

And this is what the function looks like in the angular file:

```
    $scope.getComments = function(statusid) {
Comment.get(statusid)
    .success(function(data) { 
        $scope.comments = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
};
```

And calling the API here:

```
    return {
    // get all the comments
    get : function(statusid) {
        return $http.get('/api/comments' + statusid);
    },
```

Am I missing something simple? I did not include the PHP files as that seems to all be working fine.

Comment: ng-init is not for that purpose and ofcourse you can use it with ng-repeat but ng-repeat will be evaluated first since it has higher priority for obvious reasons. You should instead call getComments() on the action that triggers the display of the list.If it is on initialization then just make the call in the controller itself.

Comment: `'/api/comments' + statusid`, did you mean `'/api/comments/' + statusid`?

Comment: As @PSL said. And the catch here is that `comments` is empty until `getComments` will set it. And it won't happen because there's no `ng-init` elements while `comments` is empty .

Comment: I think I wasn't using "GET" correctly. I updated the code and it is still not working but I think it is almost there:       `get : function(statusid) {
            return $http({
       method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/comments',
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
               params: statusid
  });
        },
`